# Does .NET DirectoryServices support LDAP-S (LDAP over SSL)?

Tags: .net, encryption, ldap, ssl, directoryservices

Does .NET DirectoryServices support LDAP-S (LDAP over SSL)?  More generally, what authentication or encryption methods are supported?

I've used the .NET System.DirectoryServices class in a project, and I do this in code:

```
using (DirectoryEntry rootDE = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPString, _usernameForSearch, _passwordForSearch, AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
```

I can see that with my corporate LDAP server, a protocol called NTLMSSP seems to be used to negotiate a session key, and the password is passed encrypted.

My question is, what other kinds of encryption will the .NET DirectoryServices class support?  Can it do the LDAP 2.0 method of switching on TLS?  Will it use SSL if the LDAP server offers it the option?

I've not been ablt to find any useful documentation on this.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are various authentication types you can use.

See here for more information.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.authenticationtypes.aspx

Comment: I still don't understand.  I don't see LDAP 2.0-style TLS listed there. Does that mean this is unsupported?  And for the options that do appear in that list - is there configuration needed, or is it enough to set that one flag and then everything happens automagically?